# Why doesn't printf display data put in a buffer with the read() function?

Tags: c

I created a file with this content: `abc` and I would like to read (only with the `read()` function, please don't suggest another one) it and display it on the console with this program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main()
{

    int fd;
    char buf[3];
    int size;

    fd = open("test",O_RDONLY);

    for (int i=0;i++;i<3){

        size = read(fd,buf,1);    // Version 2 used buf+i
        printf("%c\n", buf[i]);

    }

    close(fd);

    return 0;
}
```

I'm asking to the read function to retrieve bytes one by one, and as `chars` are one byte size I though it would work. But nothing displays on the console when executing.

Any clue?

Comment: You realize that each time you read a byte into offset zero (`buf[0]`) but you try to access elements beyond that, right?

Comment: How do you even know your `read()` call read *anything*?  You're ignoring the return value.  You don't even know if the file was opened successfully.  Also, `read()` returns `ssize_t`, not `int` - those are *not* the same.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer just edited

Comment: Ok... so have you fixed your code???  Don't keep changing the code in the question because the answers will no longer make any sense.

Comment: You changed the code, but the behavior didn't change at all?

Comment: @ScottHunter: no — there was no change because the loop was never entered and the `read` was never called and the `printf` was never called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `for` loop condition is a bit inverted. You need to swap your 2nd and 3rd part of the condition.  You have:

```
for (int i=0;i++;i<3)
```

However, `i++` evaluates to `0` during the first iteration, so the loop is never entered because the condition is false.

It should probably be:

```
 for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
```

But I'd suggest you use the return value of `read()` to determine the loop condition (and possibly use the counter if you only want to read 3 bytes).

Answer (score 2):

Each call to `read` puts the character at the start of `buf`, but you don't always print that part of `buf`.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, you read into the first entry of the `buf` array on each `read`.
Replace `size = read(fd,buf,1);` with `size = read(fd,&buf[i],1);`, and it should work.